# Codemirror crashing in php mode

Tags: php, codemirror

I use codemirror in a normal HTML/PHP project and want to write some php code. But when I want to open the php tag like

```
<?php
```

it stops after the "<" sign and doesn't let me type in anymore characters. I need to reload the site in order to make it work again.
My code is fairly simple.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="util/codemirror-5.38.0/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="util/codemirror-5.38.0/lib/codemirror.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="util/codemirror-5.38.0/theme/darcula.css">
        <script src="util/codemirror-5.38.0/mode/php/php.js"></script>
        <script src="util/codemirror-5.38.0/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="codeeditor"></div>
        <script>
            var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("codeeditor"), {
                mode: 'php',
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mime: 'text/x-php'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My issue is, that codemirror basically crashes and only a reload of the site helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. Fixed it by doing this:

Try setting the mode as `mode: text/x-php`